# Neo4j-JDBC is one JDBC connection enough for the application?

Tags: neo4j

This is regarding Neo4j-JDBC driver ,from the code of this library and also from various posts it looks like we can have a single connection cached to cater all the statements/requests in the application we just need to create new statements everytime . Please suggest if this is correct assumption ?  Or else we need to maintain a pool of objects ?

Also let me know is using  Neo4j JDBC driver is the standard way to connect through Java or we have better ways to do that(like Java API or REST interface) .

May be Michael if you can provide some insights on this .